# Resize mySql columns to accommodate encrypted data - how much?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have mySql database which use utf8_general_ci encoding.
My tables are InnoDB

CodeIgniter(3.x) is used as framework to build the php application. My plan is to encrypt some of the data, using the CodeIgniter(3.x) encryption class
for enhanced security.

I use AES-256 and the length of my encryption key is 32 bytes (characters)

Most of the columns that will be encrypted is currently of type varchar(255). I am considering increasing this value, but I don't know for how much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really comes down to the mode of operation you intend to use.  AES is a block cipher with a block size of 128 bits.  That is, 128 bits of plaintext results in 128 bits of ciphertext.

However...

Modes of operation like ECB and CBC **require** that the input data is a multiple of the block size in length.  So if, for example, you want to encrypt only 112 bits of plaintext, then your plaintext must first be padded to be a multiple of the blocksize (e.g. we add 2 bytes of padding).  This is usually done automatically by the AES implementation, but it does mean that the length of your plaintext, when encrypted, can increase by up to 16 bytes.

Modes of operation like CTR and CFB turn block ciphers into stream ciphers.  Padding is not required for stream ciphers, so 112 bits of plaintext is encrypted to 112 bits of ciphertext.

You also need to consider the need to prepend an IV/nonce.  Normally this is a 16 byte value, but GCM and CTR mode can vary.  I believe the default is 12 bytes, but I may be mistaken.

Keeping the above in mind, and assuming any data you wish to encrypt is less than or equal to your original 255 byte limit, you will need to:

- For ECB, increase the limit to 256 bytes (a perfect multiple of 16 bytes).
- For CBC, increase the limit to 256 + 16 bytes (for the IV).
- For modes that turn AES into a stream cipher (CTR, CFB etc.), the data amount can be the same (255 bytes), but you will need to make room for your nonce, which I think is normally 12 bytes.  You'll need to confirm this.

Comment: I use ctr mode, however, what makes me worry is that utf8, I have no idea if and how much will that affect the length.

Comment: You shouldn't use any character encoding at all.  Character Encodings + Raw Binary Data = Bad News.  You should store the ciphertext as raw binary.

Comment: I save the text (for example client name) as is, without any encoding but the database encoding is  utf8_general_ci encoding.

Comment: Yes, but the cell data type should be binary.

Comment: I am not messing with the cell data type at all. It is saved as is - that is done by CodeIgniter encryption class.

Comment: No, I mean the type of the data when defining the table in the database.  "Most of the columns are of the type varchar(255)" <- Change this.

Comment: Almost all fields that will be encrypted are varchar(255) data type

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying to change.  You can't store encrypted data as a string because it isn't a string, it's raw binary.

Comment: Ah, now I understand......binary 255 will do the job, no need of larger size, right?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate your time. Have a nice day Luke.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147578/discussion-between-user2417624-and-luke-park).