# Encryption questions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encryption, cryptography

I [asked a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742633/resize-mysql-columns-to-accomodate-encrypted-data-how-much) and I manage to partially implement the advice. Data is now stored encrypted in binary field (varbinary(500)), after I remove the  aes-256 encryption and I leave aes-128 (default) codeigniter encryption.

However, I have some questions, and I can't find answers, since I can not find many articles on this subject, so If anyone can answer my questions, or point me to a book, or any other literature for further reading, I would be very grateful.

1. Why encrypted data must be stored in binary type field? What is wrong with storing it in longtext, or varchar? Does that make the encryption worthless?
2. Why I must first encode the variable and then encrypt it when I store the data in the binary type of field, and I don't have to do that when I store the data in varchar field?

   ```
   base64_encode($clientName);

   $encClientName = $this->encryption->encrypt($clientName);
   ```
3. In my previous question (see the link on the top) I have been advised to use nonce. Since I didn't know how to use that with codeigniter library, I didn't implement that part. Does that make my data less secure? Can anyone post any snippet code of how to use nonce with the codeigniter?

Again, any link to reading material on this subject (storing encrypted data in the database with php) will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why encrypted data must be stored in binary type field? What is wrong with storing it in longtext, or varchar? Does that make the encryption worthless?

Encrypted data is binary. It will frequently contain byte sequences which are invalid in your text encoding, making them impossible to insert into a column which expects a string (like VARCHAR or TEXT).

The data type you probably want is either VARBINARY (which is similar to VARCHAR, but not a string) or BLOB (likewise, but for TEXT -- there's also MEDIUMBLOB, LONGBLOB, etc).

> Why I must first encode the variable and then encrypt it when I store the data in the binary type of field, and I don't have to do that when I store the data in varchar field?

You don't. This is backwards.

If you were going to use a string-type column to store encrypted data, you could "fake it" by Base64 encoding the data *after* encryption. However, you're still better off using a binary-type column, at which point you don't need any additional encoding.

> In my previous question (see the link on the top) I have been advised to use nonce. Since I didn't know how to use that with codeigniter library, I didn't implement that part. Does that make my data less secure?

Based on what I'm seeing in the documentation, I think the CodeIgniter Encryption library handles this for you by default. You shouldn't have to do anything additional.

Comment: Thanks for brief and up to the point explanations. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to duskwuffs answer, I covered your questions from a more crypto-related viewpoint.  He just managed to post a minute before I did :)

---

Encrypted data must be stored in a binary type field due to the way that Character Encodings work.  I recommend you read, if you haven't already, [this excellent article by Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) that details this very well.

It is important to remember that encryption algorithms operate on raw binary data.  That is, a bit string.  Literal 1's and 0's that can be interpreted in many ways.  You can represent this data as unsigned byte values (255, 255), Hex (0xFF, 0xFF), whatever, they are really just bit strings underneath.  Another property of encryption algorithms (or good ones, at least) is that the result of encryption should be indistinguishable from random data.  That is, given an encrypted file and a blob of CSPRNG generated random data that have the same length, you should not be able to determine which is which.

Now lets presume you wanted to store this data in a field that expects UTF8 strings.  Because the bit string we store in this field could contain **any possible sequence of bytes**, as we discussed above, we can't assume that the sequence of bytes that we store will denote actual valid UTF8 characters.  The implication of this is that binary data encoded to UTF8 and then decoded back to binary is not guaranteed to give you the original binary data.  In fact, it rarely will.

---

Your second question is also somewhat to do with encodings, but the encoding here is base64.  Base64 is a encoding that plays very nicely with (in fact, it was designed for) binary data.  Base64 is a way to represent binary data using common characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and +, /) in most implementations.  I am willing to bet that the `encrypt` function you are using either uses `base64_decode` or one of the functions it calls does.  What you should actually be interested in is whether or not the output of the `encrypt` function is a base64 string or actual binary data, as this will affect the type of data field you use in your database (e.g. binary vs varchar).

---

I believe in your last question you stated that you were using CTR, so the following applies to the nonce used by CTR only.

CTR works by encrypting a counter value, and then xor-ing this encrypted counter value with your data.  This counter value is made up of two things, the nonce, and the actual value of the counter, which normally starts at 0.  Technically, your nonce can be any length, but I believe a common value is 12 bytes.  Because the we are discussing AES, the total size of the counter value should be 16 bytes.  That is, 12 bytes of nonce and 4 bytes of counter.

This is the important part.  Every encryption operation should:

- Generate a new 12 byte nonce to use for that operation.
- Your implementation should add the counter and perform the actual encryption.
- Once you have the final ciphertext, prepend the nonce to this ciphertext so that the result is `len(ciphertext) + 12)` bytes long.
- Then store this final result in your database.

Repeating a nonce, using a static nonce, or performing more than 2^32 encryption operations with a single 12 byte nonce will make your ciphertext vulnerable.

Comment: I will need some time to re-read, digest and understand all this. Your knowledge on this subject is way above mine, and I get lost numerous times while reading your answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user2417624 Understandable.  I more intended for my answer to explain *why* as opposed to "just do this"!

Comment: I think that I will get a book on this subject in hope that I will manage to cover at leas some of the holes in my knowledge in this area. I am still reading your answer and I still can't  understand why I had to remove the aes256 in order to make my code to work, but I guess it takes time and reading. One more time, thank you for sharing your knowledge and your time.

Comment: @user2417624 Hmm do you mean you swapped AES256 for AES128 and then it worked or other way around?  Is your key in hex?  And you are welcome :)

Comment: yes, I left the default codeigniter encryption which is aes128 with CBC mode, but I am now thinking to test 256 with CBC mode instead of CTR as I  had it. Maybe it will work...

Comment: This sounds implementation specific so I'm afraid I won't be able to help with that as I know nothing about codeigniter.  My only advice is to make sure you generate/store your IV's properly if you are using CBC mode!

Comment: I have no idea what the  IV's is on the first place, but I will test it anyway...

Comment: Just to let you know that It worked. So I have now aes 256 in cbc mode, I encrypt the data and I store it in varbinary(500) field. I do not use base_encode, it just works like a charm. Thanks one more time.

Comment: @user2417624 1. The IV should be random bytes and can be prefixed to the encrypted data for use during decryption. 2. Do not report padding errors. 3. There really is no more security with 256-bits vs 128.bits, both are secure.